# Excel 2011 - How to AutoFit Wrapped Cell Referring to Another Cell?

Tags: excel, reference, word-wrap

I am working in Excel 2011 for Mac. I have a cell in my spreadsheet with wrapped text, and whenever I add to the text of that cell, the row height automatically readjusts based on the number of rows in the text of the cell. However, when I reference that cell in another cell, the height of my second cell doesn't readjust as I change the text in the original cell. I know that I can manually do this by selecting the cell and AutoFitting it, but I'd like the row height to adjust automatically. Is there a way I can do this? I've attached a photo below to illustrate my problem. As you can see, the A1 is my original cell, which has wrapped text and automatically adjust the row height. I then referenced cell A1 in cell A4 and then wrapped text in cell A4, which, as I had hoped for, AutoFit the wrapped text from A1 into A4. However, when I added text to A1, the height of A4 didn't change, as you can see as the bottom 3 lines are cut off.

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you'll always need manual intervention (or VBA) to autofit the row when the content is created with a formula. It's the same in Excel for Windows, so I'm not surprised to see that behaviour in Excel for Mac.

Comment: The VBA could be really easy: a worksheet_change event could do that everytime the first cell changes:
`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target = Cells(2, 1) Then Cells(1, 1).Rows(1).AutoFit
End Sub`